# Constructing sentences for first-order logic models

Tags: first-order-logic

would you mind checking for me if my constructions of the following sentences for a model is correct? Thanks!

1) The model has exactly one member
∃x∀y (=(x,y))

2) The model has at least 2 members

∃x∃y (¬=(x,y))

3) The model has no more than 3 members

∃x∀y (=(x,y)) v ∃x∃y∀z (¬=(x,y)&(=(z,x)v =(z,y))) v ∃x∃y∃z∀w (¬=(x,y)&¬=(x,z)¬=(y,z) & (=(w,x)v =(w,y)v =(w,z)))

4) The model is infinite

∀x∃y (<(x,y))

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For (3), your sentence is correct but far more complicated than it needs to be - I would have used a sentence that says "there are not four objects which are all different".

For (4), I assume you have some standard meaning assigned to $<$? First-order logic usually doesn't include that as an "assumed" symbol like $=$, but it's possible that your class does include it.

(1) and (2) are correct.

Comment: Thank you Reese
For (3), would this one be a more concise and correct sentence?
¬∃x∃y∃z∃w (¬=(x,y)&¬=(x,z)&¬=(x,w)&¬=(y,z)&¬=(y,w)&¬=(z,w))
And for (4), we introduced the relational symbol < to represent this infinite set

Comment: @stardust Your new sentence for (3) works great. In order for (4) to work, you need some additional meaning for $<$; otherwise, you could have the model in which the only element is $a$ and $a < a$, which satisfies your sentence.